# CloudFoundry destroyes instance right after start but not shutting down fully

Tags: java, spring, cloud, spring-integration, cloud-foundry

I am not really experienced in working with CloudFoundry. I know how to use it in terms of connecting services to an app, aswell as pushing a war, log files etc. So standard stuff.
But when it comes to configuration and behaviour of CloudFoundry my knowledge ends.

My Problem is, that right after my application is started and New Relic finished it's logging in terms of what it is using as collector etc. the CloudFoundry Cell is stopping the instance.
I use spring integration which shuts everything down because of the signal that shuts the jvm down.
I also disable several booleans in my database for some jobs.
This is all working and everythings fine until this point.

As soon as everything is shutted down CloudFoundry starts to destroy the container for the current instance. Afterwards the log entry says that the destruction was successful.
But the App is still running aswell as the instance.
My App is still logging some things (that are not the shutted down jobs) here and then and the instance seems to be still alive and not being "renewed".

Does anyone know why this is happening? Do I have to implement something into spring that blocks the instance from being destroyed? Or is this a CloudFoundry configuration which I need to make?

One weird thing is, that it only happens once peer week. Every wednesday night to thursday morning. Almost around the same time.

Edit:
Here is the log where I removed all sensitiv information

```
   Some logs which indicate that the app is still running as expected.
   
   // I think this is the part where i gets interesting.
   2020-07-09T00:44:09.87+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Cell XXX requesting replacement for instance XXX
   2020-07-09T00:44:10.37+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Cell XXX creating container for instance XXX
   2020-07-09T00:44:12.17+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Cell XXX successfully created container for instance XXX
   
   Downloading droplet, starting the application and notice that it was shutted down unexpectedly. The indication for that is a flag in the database that hasn't been set to true which would happen during a proper shutdown.
   
   2020-07-09T00:45:14.70+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Container became healthy
   
   Some New Relic information which are not important for this question.
   
   2020-07-09T00:45:19.94+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Cell XXX stopping instance XXX
   
   This is the part where the application shuts down it's listeners and jobs.
   
   2020-07-09T00:45:25.70+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 143
   2020-07-09T00:45:25.70+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Cell XXX destroying container for instance XXX
   2020-07-09T00:45:25.88+0200 [PROXY/0] OUT Exit status 137
   2020-07-09T00:45:26.07+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Cell XXX successfully destroyed container for instance XXX
   2020-07-09T00:49:36.17+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 2020-07-09T00:49:36,178+0200 Some log entry which indicates that the app is still alive
```

After that is done and the app is still running (it was not restarted inbetween) it is possible to start all jobs again by setting a flag to true which was set to false in the code of the shutdown hook so no new job would be started while the app is shutting down.

Comment: Can you show your `cf logs`, the manifest and the `cf app` output? Are you using blue-green-deployment?

Comment: @jAC I edited the question and added the logs with my suspicion but no answer how to resolve it, if my suspicion was true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now know what the problem was. Thanks to a colleague, which knew exactly what was going on as he saw the logs.

CloudFoundry is creating a new instance before destroying the old one to avoid down time.
As soon as the new instance is up and healthy it destroys the old instance.
The application which is running on the new instance still receives the shutdown signal of the old instance and executes the code in the shutdown hook. This means the flags will be set to false to stop all jobs when the app is shutting down.

To avoid this it is important to work with instance ids. Every job needs to get the id of the instance it runs on. As the new instance is starting the instance id must be overwritten in the table of the jobs. So the jobs run on the new instance and not the old one.